# In music21, how can I get it not to ignore tempo markings?

Tags: python, music21

I'm generating scores in music21, and checking them out by showing the score and hearing it with stream.show('midi'). But I find that the music21.tempo.MetronomeMark objects in the stream are simply ignored. No matter what value the the tempo object has, it plays back at what is probably 120 bpm.

Here's a short example to reproduce the problem:

```
import music21

tempo_test = music21.stream.Stream()
tempo_test.append(music21.tempo.MetronomeMark(number=20))
tempo_test.append(note.Note('C4', type='quarter'))
tempo_test.append(note.Note('F4', type='quarter'))
tempo_test.append(note.Note('B4', type='quarter'))
tempo_test.show('midi')
```

It plays back at probably 120 bpm. (also it doesn't play the first note, which is a different question.)

If I do it again with a different tempo:

```
tempo_test = music21.stream.Stream()
tempo_test.append(music21.tempo.MetronomeMark(number=200))
tempo_test.append(note.Note('C4', type='quarter'))
tempo_test.append(note.Note('F4', type='quarter'))
tempo_test.append(note.Note('B4', type='quarter'))
tempo_test.show('midi')
```

The tempo is exactly the same, probably 120.

I'm doing my work in a jupyter notebook, running python 3.6.13, and music21 5.5.0

Comment: Can you share a [mcve]? Otherwise this is likely to get closed as "Needs Details"

Comment: This is a minimal reproducible example. It would be very cumbersome to parse and annotate the binary output of the MIDI file written; this is good enough.

Answer (score -1):

This was fixed in later versions. The latest version is 6.7.1.

Comment: I'm using version 7.3.3 and have this issue - using my own code or the examples in the question, tempo is stuck at 120 bpm.

Comment: OP's example plays at 20 BPM in GarageBand and Finale for me as expected. What MIDI player are you using?

Comment: I'm not actually sure as I've been using Jupyter notebooks (in Windows, not tried in Mac), which presumably picks some sort of default player for me.